How to efficiently count maximal cliques in uniform hypergraphs
A r-uniform hypergraph is like a graph, but edges are defined as being sets of r nodes. I.e., a graph is a 2-uniform hypergraph.
Say H is an r-uniform hypergraph on n vertices.
A clique in H is a set of vertices, say C, and say |C| = k, such that all choose(k, r) r-element subsets of the vertices of C are edges of H.

Note that every (r-1) element subset of vertices is a trivial clique.
A clique is said to be maximal if no larger clique contains it.

Given a particular r-uniform hypergraph H on n vertices, how can we efficiently count the maximal cliques of H (inclusive of trivial maximal cliques).
My current approach is exhaustive search. I begin with the set of all choose(n, r-1) trivial cliques. Then, for r <= s <= n, I check every s-element subset of V(H) to see if it's a clique. If it is, I add it to my set of cliques, and remove all contained subcliques that haven't already been removed (up to s = choose(s, s-1) of these). I represent both edges and cliques as bitvectors where the i'th bit being set means node i is present in the edge or clique, though I could switch to another representation if it helps.
This can be somewhat improved by limiting the s-element subsets to those where every vertex has degree >= choose(s-1, r-1), the minimum possible degree for a member of an s-clique.
I will need to run this many times, with two possible starting conditions:

Starting condition 1: The input is an r-uniform hypergraph on n edges, and we know nothing about it's cliques.
Starting condition 2: There exists an r-uniform hypergraph on n vertices, call it H, and we have already counted the maximal cliques of H. We then form H' by 'flipping' one potential edge of H. That is, H' is identical to H except that exactly one set of r vertices is an edge H in H but not in H', or vice versa.

Since my current approach is constructive  when we get to condition 2, we not only have the maximal clique count for the solved hypergraph, but also the set of maximal cliques.
We'll encounter condition 2 much more often than condition 1.
Example:

Input: H is the complete r-uniform hypergraph on n vertices, n >= r, we have t colors, and every edge is the same color.
Output: 1 + (t-1) * choose(n, r-1)
Explanation: There is one big maximal clique, which is all of H, and for each of the (t-1) other colors, we have all trivial maximal cliques.


I think that you will get answers in https://math.stackexchange.com/ or https://mathoverflow.net/ .

@user24714692 I think you underestimate the caliber of talent here (whether or not my question piques there interest).

Question: Is this really the standard definition of clique? It implies that for r=2 a pair of vertices forms a clique iff there is an edge between them, but for r>2 every pair of vertices is a clique even if there isn't even a single hyperedge containing both---even if the hypergraph has no hyperedges at all!

@user620316 This is the standard definition of a clique. Just like a single vertex is a clique in a regular graph, every set of up to r-1 vertices in an r-uniform hypergraph H is a clique in H. I remember this took a minute to wrap my mind around the first time I encountered it too.

@user620316 It may help to think of a clique in a graph or r-uniform hypergraph as a set of vertices where every possible edge is present. The trivial cliques then are those sets of vertices where no edge is possible because the size of the vertex set is smaller than r, the size of an edge.

@Dave This last is very helpful.

@Dave But another thought: The implication seems to be that knowing the vertices and hyperedges isn't enough to determine the cliques. That is, a hypergraph has different cliques when you call it r-regular than if it's just a random hypergraph whose hyperedges happen to have the same size. Is this so? What's the definition of a clique in a non-uniform hypergraph? (Once we get past all this I promise to think about your problem, though I doubt I'll be very helpful.)

What is "choose(a,b)" function? Does it return a number?

@AlexWąsowicz choose(a, b) = a! / (b! * (a-b)!). It counts the ways to chose b elements out of a elements. E.g. if a=5 and b=2, choose(5, 2) = 10. Then, if our 5 elements are a,b,c,d,e, the 10 2-element combinations are {ab, ac, ad, ae, bc, bd, be, cd, ce, de}

Problem 1 is NP-complete or "worse"
To answer with count of all maximal cliques, algorithm first needs the set of them. To build this set from hipper graph is harder task, than to build it from graph and that is harder task,  than finding a single maximal clique of given size from graph. The last task is one of 21 NP-complete problems proven by Richard Manning Karp in 1972.
For problem to be NP-complete, the solution set (needed set to answer) needs to be check-able in polynomial time. And I don't know how this can be done for this problem, because the size of solution set isn't polynomial.
Posible acceleration for Problem 1
To my understanding, Ur current solution is going through all combinations of edges. This has time complexity of O(sum for s from r to n of choose(n, s)), or in simplified form O(n!/(n/2)!**2) (where "**" is power operator, like in Python). Instead U can grow know cliques:.

Prepare mapping from vertex to set of edges that connects to that vertex. Note, this is memory hungry operation, with complexity of O(n*choose(n-1, r-1)).
Prepare set A (a set of known cliques candidates to be maximal), by empty set.
Prepare set B (a set of candidates, but for the next iteration), by set of all trivial cliques.
Prepare count (of checked maximal cliques), by 0.
Until set B is not empty:.

Swap A with B.
While set A is not empty:.

Prepare clique A, by poping it from set A.
Prepare flag, by true.
For each vertex outside of clique A, if added to clique A, form a clique B:.

If newly formulated clique B isn't in set B, push clique B to set B.
Set flag to false.


If flag is still true, increment count.





On acceleration by additional information
Think of any additional information that might be useful. Sometimes more information can open doors to faster algorytms. I can't think of example in Ur problem, and I don't know if it exist, but just in case it helps, here is an example:.
Set can be sorted by comparison, which is the minimal information requirement for sorting. Best time complexity for this family of algorithms is T(sort) = O(T(compare)n*log n). But there are algorithms that are faster, but in exchange for more information. For example, there is an entire family of sorting algorytms that are based on layers of finite key sets. Time complexity of those is T(key_sort) = O(S(key_layers)*n).
Posible accelerations for Problem 2
First of all, raw count (without solution set) of maximal cliques in graph H does not give us anything. Edge can be a part of multiple maximal cliques. For each of those cliques, removal of its edge divides it into r maximal cliques, with equal size. So if U add an edge to graph, U only need to check growth by 1 vertex, that is from added edge. And U need to check it only for the maximal cliques, containing r-1 vertices from added edge. Then if this creates duplicates in solution set for graph H', reduce them.
In other words Problem 2 is not NP-complete, if it intakes solution set from graph H and mapping from vertices to edges (of graph H). Note there might be other information set that make this problem easier.
